# (A + D)x = b ... efficiently!

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

let say we have $A$ to be symmetric positive-definite (SPD), moreover block tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix and $D$ is block diagonal SPD (both with full rank). Let say we know everything about $A$ and $D$, e.g. theirs (eigenvalues, singular, QR, LDLT) decompositions, inverse, etc.. Is there any more efficient way to solve the given linear system then to decompose the sum $(A+D)$?

I was looking around and it seems that if the matrices have full rank, there is nothing to do with that. On the other hand, this case seems to be so special for me that I would be surprised if any particular method doesn't exist.

Comment: How about an iterative solver such as Conjugate Gradient?

Comment: By SPD you mean symmetric and positive-definite? If so, every such matrix has only positive entries on the diagonal, thus it can be decomposed to the form A+D. Then this case would not be special.

Comment: I see (Preconditioned) Conjugate Gradient as a last option since it may need various number of iterations and that is tricky for my need. I think that another point of view can be that I know inverse of $A$ but there is also $D$, which is known disturbance on the diagonal, then do I really need to compute whole inversion of $(A+D)$?

Comment: Using the Woodbury matrix identity might be more efficient that computing the whole inversion. In any case, it is never advised to explicitly compute the inversion for solving a linear system.

Comment: I suggest that you move the additional information that inverse of A is known to the text of the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I understand it well, using Woodbury can be more efficient only if $D$ has small rank (since it can be seen as a generalization of rank-one update). Yes, exactly, as written in the text, you know everything about $A$ and $D$ and anything can be "precomputed". The last comment sounds good - could you explain the idea behind?

Comment: If everything about $A$ and $D$ can be precomputed, then why not precompute $(A+D)^{-1}$ and solve $x=(A+D)^{-1}b$ in $O(n^2)$?

Comment: Everything about $A$ and $D$, but separately ;). I just formulate it in this way. In my experiment $D$ is changing every time and $A$ and $b$ are static...

Comment: Well, if $A$ is block tridiagonal, its Cholesky factorisation takes $O(N)$ operations where $N$ is the problem size (I guess in this case the triangular factor is block bidiagonal). Same holds for that of $A+D$. It cannot be updated more efficiently than in $O(N)$ operations.

Comment: Thanks. You are probably right. I was just convinced that a prior information about banch of problems (even general ones) can helps with solving its sum. The factorization takes $O(N(\ldots))$ since it depends on overall problem size but also size of blocks - maybe there is some space for improvent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some cases it could be useful to compute approximate solution by the following way:

\begin{align}
(A+D)x &= b\\
x &= (D(D^{-1}A+I))^{-1}b=\\
 &= (I+X)^{-1}D^{-1}b,\\
\end{align}

where $X = D^{-1}A$ and since we know that

$\|X\|<1:\quad(I+X)^{-1} = I-X+X^2-X^3\ldots$

we can write our solution as

$\|D^{-1}A\|<1:\quad x = (D^{-1}-D^{-1}AD^{-1}+D^{-1}AD^{-1}AD^{-1}-D^{-1}AD^{-1}AD^{-1}AD^{-1}\ldots)b$
or similarly
$\|A^{-1}D\|<1:\quad x = (A^{-1}-A^{-1}DA^{-1}+A^{-1}DA^{-1}DA^{-1}-A^{-1}DA^{-1}DA^{-1}DA^{-1}\ldots)b$

and then approximate it by only finite many terms. Noticed that the smaller eigenvalues $\|D^{-1}A\|$ has in the first case (or $\|A^{-1}D\|$ in the second one) the faster series converge to zero and thus less terms may be used to reach the same accuracy.